# NodeJS express unresolved function or method get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, undefined

I'm trying to use express with Pug (Jade) to render/display a page and the function get() is coming back undefined with warnings...

I've run:

```
npm install express --save

npm install pug --save
```

Heres the top of the JS file with undefined get method...

```
var app = require('express')();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      console.log("test");  //line isn't reached
      res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
  });
```

No errors when running, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Is the render working ? Your browser renders the index page ? have you started the express server ?

Comment: @v1shnu That line doesn't get reached, along with the console.log.  app.set  isn't throwing any errors or warning

Comment: Can you show me the code which has the express server running ? because without starting the server and without hitting the root url, the get method will not be invoked.

Comment: @v1shnu So i have a different server running and the app.get is inside the function I'm sending responses with.  The lines above in this function get invoked (before and after the app.get).  I can't figure out why the get method is undefined, but every other express function is fine

Comment: can you paste the full code here. It's very hard to debug with just that.

Comment: @v1shnu its for an assignment so id rather not post everything, is there another way i can get it to you.

Comment: if you have the code on Github or something, you can share the link here. I can take a look.

Comment: @v1shnu https://gist.github.com/tdirusso/4dc6233a5f51572823b5b77f16b3cb64

Comment: I'm getting page not found !

Answer (score 3):

You need to start the express server by

```
app.listen(9000, function(){
console.log('Server started...');
});
```

Add this line to the bottom of your JS file. Then open your browser and hit the url:

```
localhost:9000
```

Only then will the GET method call be invoked by express.